# crash on initialization of AdMob, occuring on android 11 devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

I am initilizing AdMob in application class. for some devices with android 11 a crash occurs.
related logs:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 10275
```

```
Remote stack trace:
    at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(AppOpsManager.java:7794)
    at com.android.server.ConnectivityService.ensureSufficientPermissionsForRequest(ConnectivityService.java:5672)
    at com.android.server.ConnectivityService.requestNetwork(ConnectivityService.java:5767)
    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IConnectivityManager.java:1570)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
```

I was not able to reproduce the crash and I was wondering if anyone else encountered this issue.

Comment: did you found a fix

Comment: no, not yet. and the issue still exists in my project.

Comment: It would be helpful to share how you init AdMob. I use AdMob and I have not seen this problem before.

Comment: @Rob I just call MobileAds.intialize in the application class. it is weird that it only happens on android 11.

Comment: can you share your gradle and Manifest file?